# Deploy ReadyRoll Database Package task gives error as “‘sqlcmd.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, readyroll

I added the **Deploy ReadyRoll Database Package** task in VSTS release definition for deploying the ReadyRoll SQL Server Database Project using Migration Approach.

I followed this [link](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Getting+started+with+ReadyRoll) to create ReadRoll SQL Server Database Project in VS2017.

I configured the build definition using Hosted VS2017 Agent in VSTS like this below figure.

[image]

And also configured the configured release definition using Hosted VS2017 Agent in VSTS like this below figure.

[image]

After that, I created release in Hosted VS2017 then I faced the issue like this below figure
[image]

But here I used the Azure SQL Server and Database with SQL Server Authentication.

Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue as soon as possible?

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set Sysem.debug to true)

Comment: This is link for logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvXScnKqU7qyXkZy2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding PowerShell task before Deploy ReayRoll Database Package:

Type: Inline Script

Inline Script:

```
$sqlcmd = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn";
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};${sqlcmd}";
```

Comment: Even I added Powershell script before Deploy Ready Roll Database package, still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @pradeep Add System.Debug variable and set it to true, then start a release and share the logs on the OneDrive.

Comment: This is the links for logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvgIZKIUc4g8dw4Zc

Comment: @pradeep Based on the error, there is pre-deployment script to create KZWU-RES-DB-02 database, but it is already existing, so it fails, using different database instead or delete the existing database.

Comment: @pradeep What's the detail error message in the log? You can share it again.

Comment: currently I used the Local SQL database connection details to apply local database migrations sucessfully. But whenever I used azure SQL database connection details to apply local database migrations it gives the error like "sqlcmd.exe exited with a non-zero exit code."

Comment: @pradeep try removing `Pre-Deployment\01_Create_Database.sql` from the project (that script should contain conditions to prevent it from trying to create a DB that already exists, but that doesn't seem to be working). Also please ensure that you are using ReadyRoll 1.14.8 or later.

Comment: @pradeep Share the log files on the OneDrive.

Comment: This is the links for logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvhPoCMyGJuOvyNCt

Comment: @pradeep Based on the log, the error still is Database 'KZWU-RES-DB-03' already exists, remove Pre-Deployment\01_Create_Database.sql and try again.

Comment: I already tried by removing 01_Create_Database.sql file but still I got same issues. this is the link of logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvW6dtNl_Gjqzl0pQ

Comment: @pradeep The error is USE statement is not supported to switch between databases, could you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: This is my simple project https://1drv.ms/f/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvhbBKUh4cmG2jh6m

Comment: @pradeep Right click project in VS=> Properties=>Project Settings=>Choose Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12 in Target platform, then check in changes and build, release.

Comment: Thanks @starain, you saved my time. now its working with out any issues